# Is it possible to have an Adafruit music maker shield and a sensor connected to the same Arduino?

Tags: shields, adafruit

Are the analog I/O pins on the Arduino still available for sensors when there is an Adafruit Music Maker shield attached to it? I want to play a sound file, but only when a PIR sensor senses motion.

Comment: What does the schematic and/or datasheet for the music maker say?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the PCB of the Adafruit Music Maker here:

https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/16643

You can see that there are no connections on the analog I/O of the Arduino.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer a bit? Actual pin numbers would be great.